# Discord Bot isn't working to detect if a member has the muted role already

Tags: discord, discord.js

**So I am pretty new to this. I can't seem to find out why my bot doesn't detect when a player has the muted role or not.**

I thought that if I put "If (Mute)" it will detect if a member has the role "Muted". The only thing it does is say "That member is muted already", even though the member doesn't have the role at all. I've even switched it around to check if the member has the "Member" role, and if it does, remove that role and add the mute role, of which it does, but then it still won't detect if the member has the muted role, and will only do "@member has been muted!", not "That member is muted already"

**Code:**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: "Mute members",
    execute(message, args, Discord, client) {

        const Admin = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'AdminIDGoesHere');
        const Mod = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'ModIdGoesHere');

        if (Admin || Mod) {

            const target = message.mentions.users.first();
            let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            let Mute = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'MutedIdGoesHere');
            let Member = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'MemberIdGoesHere');

            if (target) {

                if (Mute) {

                    message.reply("That member is muted already!")

                } else {

                    memberTarget.roles.add(Mute);
                    memberTarget.roles.remove(Member);
                    message.reply(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted!`).then(msg => {
                        msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
                    })
                }


            } else {
                message.reply("Couldn't find that member!").then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
                })
            }


        } else {
            message.reply("You don't have permission to do that!").then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            })
        }

    }
}
```

And like I said, I'm pretty new to this so lol. I've looked up for hours on how to do this and I feel like its a simple fix that I just can't see, think of, or find. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the correct role ID's?

Comment: Yeah I do have the right ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited*

You can change your if statement into something like this:

```
if(!member.roles.has('MuteRoleID')) { return
}else {
member.addRole('MuteRoleID')
member.removeRole('MemberRoleID')
 message.reply(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted!`).then(msg => {
                        msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 });
}
```

If this doesn't work i will run it in my code and see whats the issue :)

Comment: It just tells me `TypeError: message.guild.members.cache.fetch is not a function`

Comment: Updated it a bit. Give it another try with the Edited code

Comment: Did you use the (' target.id ' )? It is not supposed to be a function. Instead, it should be a String! Make sure you use the (' ') in the parenthesis and update if you see another problem!

Comment: Alright I used the updated version. I also tried it with and without the (' ')
Without it, it'll give no error.
With it, it will give this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError:
Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "target.id" is not snowflake.`
As well the bot will procced to say with and without (' ') "That member is muted already!" even though they don't have it.

Comment: Don't know if role.add is still a thing in v12. Try the edited post, if it doesnt work i will run it in my code and give you a full report

Comment: Hi I just now got back on this project. But I have figured it out thanks to your help. Though some things needs to be changed due to v12. I'll edit your post and put it as the answer! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use

```js
const MutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("ROLE_ID");
const Member = message.member; //No need to add this Variable
```

Then

```js
message.member.roles.has(MutedRole.id) ? message.member.roles.cache.add(MutedRole) : message.channel.send("This user is already muted")
```